# PHP Zebra Forms Framework fetching values from MySQL for Select Box

Tags: php, mysql

Iam using a PHP form framework called Zebra Forms.

My requirement is that i need to fetch values from MySQL and populate the select box.

How can i accomplish that. The select box only accept arrays as values.

My sample code is

```
<?PHP
$rs = "SELECT * FROM country";
$options = array('Pick a country');
foreach($result as $row)
$options[$row->id]  = $row->country;
$obj = $form->add('select', 'country_name');
$obj->add_options($options, true);
?>
```

I got this sample from a website. But its not working. How can i do it.

Your guidance is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Do you even execute the SQL query somewhere? If so, please post that code as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have not done this with MySQL. But my attempt with MSSQL worked as follows. Hope this helps you for Zebra Form. Refer Syntax and following example.

```
    $obj->add_options(array(
    'v1' => 'Value 1',
    'v2' => 'Value 2',
    'v3' => 'Value 3'
    ));
```

http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/docs/Zebra_Form/Controls/Zebra_Form_Select.html

My Example:

```
    $obj = $form->add('select', 'my_select');

    if(sqlsrv_has_rows($query_memtype)){
        while($rec0 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_memtype, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {         
          $obj->add_options(array(
             $rec0['MType_Id'] => $rec0['MType_Description'] ));
                }
            }
```